# If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix with full rank and only simple roots, what can be said about $|B\otimes I+I\otimes B|$, for $B = \sum_k a_k A^k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, symmetric-polynomials

I'm considering a situation in which $A, B > 0$ are real $(p\times p)$ symmetric matrices where $A$ has $p$ distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^p$, and $AB=BA$. I'm interested in the level of constraint placed on the matrix $B$ given these assumptions.

For example, according to the Wikipedia on [Commuting Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices), the minimal polynomial of $A$ coincides with it's characteristic polynomial, so
$$B = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \alpha_k A^k.$$

While I would be glad to hear more generally about the constraints associated with the matrix $B$, my particular question is with the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) (denoted by $|\cdot|$) of the [Kronecker Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition) (denoted by $\oplus$):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|B\oplus B| = |B\otimes I + I \otimes B| &\propto \prod_{i \leq j} (\delta_i + \delta_j)\\
 &= \prod_{i\leq j} \left(\sum_k \alpha_k (\lambda_i^k + \lambda_j^k)\right),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\propto$ represents a proportionality relation with respect to the arguments of interest, $\otimes$ represents the [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), and $\{\delta_i\}_{i=1}^p$ are the eigenvalues of $B$.

The question is: For $\vec{\alpha} = (\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_{p-1}) \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\vec{\lambda} = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{p}) \in \mathbb{R}^p$, do there exist functions $h(\vec{\alpha})$ and $g(\vec{\lambda})$ such that

$$|B\oplus B| = h(\vec{\alpha}) + g(\vec{\lambda})?$$

$$|B\oplus B| = h(\vec{\alpha}) g(\vec{\lambda})?$$

I am also interested in decoupling $\vec{\lambda}$ from any form of "additional information" given by the polynomial. For example, if $B$ is expressed in a factored form:

$$B = \prod_{l=1}^{L} (A - c_lI)^{n_l},$$

or via [Cayley-Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem):

$$|B\oplus B| \propto \prod_{i\leq j}\left( \prod_{l=1}^L (\lambda_i - c_l)^{n_l} + \prod_{l=1}^L (\lambda_j - c_l)^{n_l} \right)$$

do such functions exist for $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{\lambda}$, respectively?

Thanks for your consideration.

**Update:**

I have worked some amount further on the problem. I use the shorthand $p_{kij}$ to denote the [power sum symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) $p_k(\lambda_i,\lambda_j)$ and rewrite and expand the determinant above.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 \prod_{i\leq j}\left(\sum_{k} \alpha_k(\lambda_i^k + \lambda_j^k) \right) &= \prod_{i\leq j}\left(\sum_{k} \alpha_kp_{kij}\right).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I note if all $p_{kij} = 1$, the expansion is the [complete symmetric homogeneous polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial) $h_k(\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_{p-1})$. Even when the $p_{kij}$ differ the power expansion of the $\alpha_k$ remain the same. I consider a vector $h(\vec{\alpha})$ with elements according to the terms of $h_k(\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_{p-1})$. Then

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\prod_{i\leq j}\left(\sum_{k} \alpha_kp_{kij}\right) &= h(\vec{\alpha})^\top g(\vec{\lambda}),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $g(\vec{\lambda})$ has elements made up of combinations of $p_{kij}$ mapped from $\lambda$. The geometric definition of the dot product still suggests dependence via

$$\vec{h}^\top\vec{g} = \|\vec{h}\|\|\vec{g}\|\cos(\theta),$$

so I'm unsure one can eliminate dependence without an extreme assumption such as orthogonality. I have re-tagged this to include symmetric polynomials in case I can pick anyone's brain from that space.

Comment: Please explain your symbols. E.g. what is $|M|$?

Comment: As you are only interested in determinants and eigenvalues you should diagonalise everything: first $A$, and then the $AB=BA$ condition forces $B$ to be diagonal too (and every diagonal $B$ is possible). It's now trivial to compute the determinant in terms of the $\delta_i$. But as I can't understand what you mean by  $\propto$ I can't go further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and apologies for the unclear notation- by $\propto$ I mean up to a constant of proportionality. I believe the determinant is the full product of the eigenvalues rather than the triangular product. I specify triangular because this is a sub-question of a larger problem in which I'm dealing with [elimination matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices).  My larger problem also deals with specifying probability distributions on $\vec{\alpha}$ and $\vec{\lambda}$ so I'm interested in the relationship between those quantities in particular.

Comment: Yes, of course the determinant is the product of all the $\delta_i+\delta_j$. But this isn't a constant multiple of the product of those with $i\le j$: so I really don't understand what you are asserting by $\propto$.

Comment: The proportionality relation is used to avoid definition of the [elimination matrix $L_p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices), along with it's [Moore-Penrose inverse $L_p^+$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), in the "true" determinant statement $|L_p^+[(B\otimes I) + (I\otimes B)]L_p|$, as they are superfluous to my particular question; if one can find such functions $g(\cdot), h(\cdot)$ in this case, whether the product is over $i\leq j$ or $i,j$ should be irrelevant.

Comment: Last comment: as stated here it seems to me to be a statement about symmetric functions in the $\delta_i$ and $\lambda_i$ which are connected by by the polynomial with coefficients $\alpha_i$. I'd look in books on that topic to see if there are identities.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have done some reading regarding symmetric polynomials and it is helping to see the problem in a different light.